# How to change default view for SharePoint Document Folder

Tags: 2013, list, document-library, list-view, configuration

I would like to change the default view for a SharePoint list.

Currently, it organizes the list by the name alphabetically. I want it to organize it by time modified (newest to oldest).

I already performed the following:

```
Library -> Library Settings -> All Items (the current default view)
```

Then I set "`First sort by the column:`" to "`Modified`" and "`Show items in descending order`".
I set "`Then sort by column:`" to "None"

I saved this configuration, and it sorts by "`modified`" correctly. However, I have this app on a separate page, and on that separate page, it still sorts by name. I've never had this problem before. Is there a way to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try editing the web part and re-select the view.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to edit the webpart and change the view of the webpart to the "All Items" view that you just edited. Each webpart can have their own anonymous view that isn't tied back to a list, but is custom to that specific webpart. All you need to do is change the view of the webpart at the top of the webpart properties.